# An exponential upper bound for Bessel K function?

Tags: inequality, special-functions, bessel-functions

I saw a bound of the form:

$$K_\nu(x) \leq Ce^{-x} \quad\text{for $x \geq 1$}$$

i.e. an exponential bound, somewhere, but I have no reference. Could someone tell me if this true?

Comment: Does $C$ depend on $\nu$? At any rate, cf. http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mariom/AM282-01/HANDOUTS/Abramowitz_Stegun_Chapter_9.pdf gives at least asymptotic expansions.

Comment: Hmm, I think it can @ian. Thanks will check out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $\log K_\nu(x)$ is a convex function (it is a consequence of Turan's inequality for Bessel functions) and
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\log K_\nu(x)}{x} = -1, $$
hence we have for sure:
$$ \forall x\geq 1, \qquad K_{\nu}(x) \leq \left(e\cdot K_\nu(1)\right) e^{-x}.$$